# PKCS#11 HSM Remember Password

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I need that after the first time windows ask for the HSM PIN it is memorized for the next calls

```
cert = Cert.GetCertificateFromStore();

RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;

byte[] text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Assinged"); ;
ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(text);
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, false);
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, cert);
signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid(CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

// create the signature
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear. Which Window? if you need remember a variable you can set a variable in comand line whit
String pin = sc.nextLine();
ready!!

Comment: Use Comments to request more details about a question rather than an Answer.

Comment: the problem is that this window you see above it comes from SignedCms, I can't modify the windows program for that